# Python OpenCV image editing: Faster way to edit pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-editing

Using python (openCV2, tkinter etc) I've created an app (a very amateur one) to change blue pixels to white. The images are high quality jpgs or PNGS.

The process: Search every pixel of an image and if the 'b' value of BGR is higher than x, set pixel to white (255, 255, 255).

The problem: There are about 150 pictures to process at a time, so the above process takes quite long. It's around 9 - 15 seconds per iteration depending on the images size (resizing the image speeds up the process, but not ideal).

Here is the code (with GUI and exception handling elements removed for simplicity):

```
for filename in listdir(sourcefolder):
        # Read image and set variables 
        frame = imread(sourcefolder+"/"+filename)
        rows = frame.shape[0]
        cols = frame.shape[1]

        # Search pixels. If blue, set to white. 
        for i in range(0,rows):
            for j in range(0,cols):
                if frame.item(i,j,0) > 155:
                    frame.itemset((i,j,0),255)
                    frame.itemset((i,j,1),255)
                    frame.itemset((i,j,2),255)
        imwrite(sourcecopy+"/"+filename, frame)
        #release image from memory 
        del frame
```

Any help on increasing efficiency / speed would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use numpy's [where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method instead of your quadratic loop

Comment: Maybe you  don't  have  to  access  pixels  like  that in python    try : img_bgr[mask > x] = [255, 0, 0]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with this image:

[image]

Then use this:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('a.png') 

# Make all pixels where Blue > 150 into white
im[im[...,0]>150] = [255,255,255]

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much. Iterations are down to 0.8 seconds. I'm astonished at the simplicity of the code as well. 

Are all the pixels accessed simultaneously? I guess my amateur instincts is to do exhaustive iteration. Thanks again.

Comment: We are all amateurs compared to some folk - main thing is to try to keep learning :-) It uses Numpy underneath and is all heavily optimised for us.

Comment: Should `result.png` exist before `cv2` can write to it?

Comment: @MehdiCharife It doesn't matter if it exists or not - it will get written either way.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried doing the equivalent to a video file (by using the `VideoWriter` class but it kept giving me errors  creating the file before hand with the `open` function (using `x` as the option) solved the problem So I assumed a similar issue would be in images

Answer (score 2):

Use cv2.threshold to create  a mask using x threshold value.

Set  the color like this :  img_bgr[mask == 255] = [255, 0, 0]